# How to call method from DAL to BAL

Tags: c#, asp.net

These is my method in DAL is either

```
public DataTable deleteRole(string getUserID)
{
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = conn;
    myCommand.CommandText = "Delete From UserRole Where UserID = @UserID";
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", getUserID);

    conn.Open();

    int i = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = myCommand;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

or

```
public Dataset something(){}
```

and I know how to call it from DAL to BAL.

This is how I call from DAL to BAL:

```
public DataTable getUpdatedRole(string getUserID)
{
    return sDal.deleteRole(getUserID);
}
```

but I have a problem where one of my method in DAL is

```
public int something () {}
```

and I am not sure how do I call it in the BAL.

How do I call it from DAL to BAL?

eg code in DAL

```
public int something(string somthing)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString))

    {
        string insertsql = "INSERT INTO Table(xx) OUTPUT INSERTED.addID  values (@xx)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertsql,conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xx", xx);
        conn.Open();
        var table1Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return table1Id;
    }
}
```

How do I call it in my BAL?

Comment: share the code where u are hvng issues

Comment: did you have dll refrenced correctly i.e in BAL DAL dll should be present

Comment: above. I have that code in my DAL but i am not sure how should i call in BLL. @YashveerSingh

Comment: please correctly format it it is unreadable

Comment: done. i just need to know how can i call something method in DAL in BLL. Since it is an int method, i am not sure how should i call it in BLL @YashveerSingh

Comment: int i =  new DAL.ClassName.something('something ');

Comment: this will work only if you have DAL DLL refrenced  present in BAL

Comment: I dont get it. give me a moment i try to put more eg in my q

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question @YashveerSingh

Comment: hi your information is incomplete i dont see DAL class name . project name  how did you structured your project without all this it will be impossible to tell .

Comment: chk my answer i hope it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method is in BAL . Assuming sDal is the object of the class where something method is defined you can call like this.

```
public intgetSomething(string getUserID)
{
    int i = sDal.something(getUserID);
    return i;
}
```